# Android Multitouch, getting the postion data at particular time (without regard of it's history)

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am having probs with multitouch on android and I believed I worked it out, however problems appear to still arise sometimes. I know there are many answers to similar questions (here and elsewhere) but I have not yet found solution to this particular case.

In a way my problem is quite simple: I have a timer, and each time it's run I wish to know how many fingers are down and where they are. I am NOT interested in their history, whether they've moved or if one has gone up since last time, just get the position of what is touching now.

So put another way, I don't want to run a process when ever a touch event occus, I want to get current touch data (postion of a finger touching sceen) when a process is run.

(After Ragnagord suggetion I relise I should have said how I had tried before. What tried to do was to have booleans that would be "true" if down (moved, etc) and "false" when up (cancel, etc), then when I ran the process it would check which was true or false. This sorted worked though it would fail sometimes and become a mess. Also I felt this to be a bit of a hack and there should be a nice way of going about it.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution would be to set events that set a boolean to false or true on touch at up and down events, so if the boolean is true, the screen is currently touched. Also you can store the x and y values in variables or something. This way you can read the information from the timer event. (i don't know much about android events, but this seems logical to me)

Comment: This was what I tried and thought was working but it fails sometimes. It misses ups sometimes and then becomes a mess. It's like something gets confused or overloaded with touch data or something.